Issue in audio-sender pipeline when checking for signal via a shared flag in gstreamer
I'm using a gstreamer pipeline to send audio which is a separate p_thread, where I'm trying to terminate and cleanup on receiving a signal(SIGINT) which is indicated by a global cleanup_flag(set as true). So I'm continuously checking if the flag is set true, if so then I change its state to GST_STATE_NULL. If not it is set to GST_STATE_PLAYING. This doesn't seem to work for audio, but the same logic works for the video pipeline. Is there any fundamental behavior of these pipelines that affects this?
This doesn't seem to work(no audio is sent), even if I put the gst_element_set_state(pipeline, GST_STATE_PLAYING); line before the loop.
while (!cleanup_flag) {
                gst_element_set_state(pipeline, GST_STATE_PLAYING);
                g_usleep(100000);  // Small sleep to prevent tight looping
    }
    if(cleanup_flag)
    {
        gst_element_set_state(pipeline, GST_STATE_NULL);  // Stop the pipeline gracefully
        gst_object_unref(pipeline);
    }

But the same works fine for a video-sender(video is sent fine):
